# Change button color when a button in another activity is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

I'm new in Android programming and I still have sometimes small problems. My problem currently is the following:

I have 2 activities with just one button in each. The button of the first activity is opening the second activity. But when I press the button in the second activity, the Text in the Button of the first activity should change to "Hello" and the color should be red.

I have managed to change the text but not the color. Could someone help me please?

My Code:

First activity:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button placeHolder;
Intent intent;

public void button0(View v){

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    placeHolder = findViewById(R.id.button);

    placeHolder.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));
}
}
```

The code of second activity:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


public void buttonOnClick(View v){

    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", "Hello");
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line of code in your first activity where you set your text to your button:

To change background color:

```
placeHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

To change text color:

```
placeHolder.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

**Usage:** 
 **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button placeHolder;
Intent intent;

public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

public void button0(View v){

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    placeHolder = findViewById(R.id.button);
}

    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

    // check if the request code is same as what is passed
  
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {  
       placeHolder.setText(data.getStringExtra("message"));
       placeHolder.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    }  

}
```

**MainActivity2:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


public void buttonOnClick(View v){

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("message", "Hello");
    setResult(MainActivity2.REQUEST_CODE, intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
}
```

Comment: After adding the "placeHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));" the program made the Button red by starting the application. I guess because its in onCreate method.

Comment: Isn't that what you need?

Comment: No. I want after pressing the button in the second activity to return me back to the first activity and to set also the button of the first activity to red color and the text. Not when I start my program from the very beginning.

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: It worked but I had to change the setTextColor to setBackroundColor but this was not a problem :) Thank you so much for supporting me!!! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use startActivityforResult() insted of startActivity() and then when you come back from second class to the first class then set red color tor your button onActivityResult() function thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Because I haven't heard about this, I will read in google first of how to use this. :)

Comment: in second activity change buttonOnclick function to this 
public void buttonOnClick(View v){
setResult(RESULT_OK,new Intent().putExtra("color","red").Intent.putExtra("message","Hello")) 
finish()
}

Comment: and in main activity change startActivity(intent);
to  startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

and create overide function 

void onActivityResult(Int requestCode, Int resultCode,  Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
  placeHolder.setText(data.getStringExtra("message"));
  String color=data.getStringExtra("color");
  if(color.equals("red")){
  //and change color here
  }
  
 }

}

hope it will work for you

Comment: Use this one it will help you and you have not need of call intent from second activity use startactivityforresult from first activity then do what you want to doing in second activity and then send back data to the main class this is best practice for your question

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help! I combined your solution with the solution above (another user) and now I understood it perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GreenRobot. Then you can do anything from other activities.
Here is the link [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0):

**Second Activity:**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", "Hello");
    intent.putExtra("color", -65536); //-65536 is color RED int value
    startActivity(intent);
```

**First Activity**

```
placeHolder.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));
placeHolder.setBackgroundColor(getIntent().getStringExtra("color",0)); // 0 is default value
```